# Compose key doesn't work, even though set in /etc/default/keyboard

Tags: lubuntu, compose-key

In Lubuntu 15.10 even though in /etc/default/keyboard it is set that `XKBOPTIONS="compose:rctrl"`, no compose key works when using Right Ctrl. The system doesn't even register it as compose key (any letter I type after pressing it is printed on screen, it doesn't wait for a combination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard Layout Handler seems to override the system settings, so [this is how you solve the problem:](http://lubuntu.me/tip-compose-key/)

1. Right-click on the language flag in the bottom right.
2. Select "'Keyboard Layout Handler Settings' Settings".
3. Under "Advanced setxkbmap Options" input `compose:rctrl` and click on the little "save" button in the right end of the input box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to Lubuntu, but here's the solution for regular Ubuntu:

/etc/default/keyboard doesn't seem to matter. It doesn't have XKBOPTIONS filled in on my system even though I have the compose key enabled. What does matter is the gconf setting 'org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options'. You can edit it via `dconf` or use terminal like so:

Check the current value:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

If the above just returned empty brackets, run this, and you're done:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:rctrl']"
```

Comment: Nope. I did that and now the output is `['compose:rctrl']`, but the rctrl still doesn't function as a compose key...

Comment: Maybe you need to log out and back in. Try restarting too, for the heck of it.

Comment: Tried that as well, but still nothing.